# Issue with programmatical alignment inside Relative layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I am trying to add a RelativeLayout programmatically. The layout contains an imageview and a textview horizontally. Now both are overlapping. How to set the alignment properly with LayoutParams programmatically?

```
        RelativeLayout rl  = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("test");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
        item.setImageResource(image);
        myparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        tv.setLayoutParams(myparam);
        rl.addView(item);
        rl.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Check this code now..this will help

RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

ImageView item = new ImageView(this); 
item.setImageResource(image); 
item.setId(1);
item.setLayoutParams(newParams);     
rl.addView(item);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView tv = new TextView(this); tv.setText("test"); 
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
tv.setLayoutParams(lprams); 
lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1); 

rl.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Text is not visible in this

Comment: your textview color is white, check for background color ,if background color is white , change txtview to other color.

Comment: background is black only.

Comment: add this line in textview part  lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

Comment: Thanks. It still overlaps on the right edge of the image. How can I  overcome it?

Comment: please write  lprams.leftMargin="some int value"

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify how the `TextView` and `ImageView` are **related** in their respective `LayoutParams`. You can use the [`addRule`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29) method to do the same.

For egs:

```
item.setId(A_POSITIVE_INTEGER);
myparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, item.getId());
tv.setLayoutParams(myparam);
```

will make the `TextView` appear below the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this); RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myparam = new           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView tv = new TextView(this); tv.setText("test"); 
tv.setId(1);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
tv.setLayoutParams(lprams); 
rl.addView(tv);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

ImageView item = new ImageView(this); 
item.setImageResource(image); 
newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1); 
item.setLayoutParams(newParams);     
rl.addView(item);
```

Comment: Hey, it aligns the text on the left to the image

Comment: yes, if you want imageview on left then use imageview code first and then textview, that way you will get imageview and textview properly aligned..thanks